# How do I diagnose / fix a Hard Drive that has suddenly become slow?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

My PC has two drives -- an HDD (D:) and an SSD (C:). Today, I've noticed that read operations on the HDD are taking an inordinate amount of time.

If I open both drives and right-click "Program Files(x86)" -> Properties, the SSD discovers 23.8 GB in about 15 seconds, and the HDD discovers... well, it's been 10 minutes, and it has only found 300 MB worth of files and folders. This is the drive my Steam library is installed on, so there should be hundreds of gigs worth of discovery.

What are my next steps in terms of diagnose / repair? I can't run checkdisk (or rather, I can, but who's to say how long it will take to run), and the problem persists through both restart and full-shut down operations.

Edit:
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure it will help you or not but give it a try:
https://www.easeus.com/partition-manager-software/hard-drive-very-slow-suddenly.html#:~:text=Switch%20the%20SATA%20Data%20Cable,that%20slows%20down%20your%20HDD.

Comment: Please run a SMART test on the failing HDD and edit the question to include the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the HDD might be failing. [Check the disk status](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-check-if-hard-drive-failing-smart-windows-10).

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>, type *cmd*, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to open a CMD prompt as Administrator.
- Enter `wmic diskdrive get status` for the overall status of connected drives. You should see `OK` for each.
- Enter `wmic /namespace:\\root\wmi path MSStorageDriver_FailurePredictStatus` to see a prediction of disk failure, based on [S.M.A.R.T.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) data.
- Under `Acive` should be `TRUE`, and under `PredictFailure` should be `FALSE`.

If the disk is failing, stop using it immediately to prevent further damage, and save its contents. The easiest way to do this is to boot from a USB flash drive with WinPE (AKA WinRE) or a live Linux distro and use disk imaging software to copy the entire HDD to another. [Macrium Reflect Free](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree), for example, can create a boot USB drive which can image the HDD without further writing to it.

Once you have an image, replace an ailing drive and either restore the image to the drive, or copy data from the image to the new drive.

Comment: Hm. No dice checking the disk status that way (see the edited screenshot in the OP). If the read speed of the drive has gone down, wouldn't any software that tried to copy it run into the same issue?

Comment: Absolutely! That's why it's necessary to save as much as you can, before it stops working altogether, if it were failing. However, from the diagnostics, it doesn't seem failure is imminent, so there may be another cause for that slowness.